# Openid and types of data

Tags: java, openid, openid-provider

I'm trying to implement an Openid server and the problem is: Exchange special data types.

As i understood on openid you can only exchange ns and ax data schemas for other types of data you should implement a new schema and a new extension for the library to support the new schema. Is this right ? And what should be the easiest to add this special data ?

tks for ur time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AX can support both strings and lists of strings out of the box. This works well for most bits, like numbers, names, and the like. Since AX uses URLs as its keys, you can define your own semantics to the value, as long as it can fit into a URLencoded string. Thus, if you need more structure in your response, you can always serialize your values as JSON objects and pack them into the AX values. Keep in mind that this will explode the size of your requests fairly quickly and you could run into 413 errors before you know it.

Comment: humm ok. is it possible add more variables ? like ax schema have name, telephone, email. can i add new variables like car license number, laptop ip address or things like that ?

Comment: @Winter: Yes, you can add whatever variables you want. You're not limited to what's listed in axschema, and as long as the variables you are using are set as URLs, you should be just fine. So you could do something like: openid.ax.fn=http://yourdomain.com/customfield and then have your server know how to send back data for that AX key. Like I said above, that data could be formatted in a number of ways to house a complex object.

Comment: are u sure ? i tried to add a attribute ax and in the end i failed... the error was like openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
 attribute not valid or something like that. :S

Comment: @Winter I'm positive. Make sure your namespaces are correct as well. Please post more details about what you want to send and the error that you're getting so that we can help you better.